# Batch file For loop not expanding variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a bat script that's supposed to move around some build artifacts. I need it to loop through a few different values (represented below as `ABC`, `DEF`, and `GHI`). I also would like to create temporary environment variables along the way. However, the environment variables introduced inside the loop don't ever get expanded.

```
@echo on

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Remove the OutputMSI directory
set output=OutputMSI

for %%x in (ABC DEF GHI) do (
    :: Create a new Output tree
    set products_dir=%output%\%%x\products
    mkdir %products_dir%

    :: Copy published files
    robocopy publish\%%x\ %products_dir% *.application *.deploy /s

    :: Copy Version.txt
    copy Version.txt %products_dir%
)

endlocal
```

This is what gets echoed (with comments inline):

```
C:\...>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\...>set output=OutputMSI

C:\...>for %x in (ABC DEF GHI) do (
set products_dir=OutputMSI\%x\products
===>             ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^ %output% gets expanded here
 mkdir
 ===>  ^^^^^^^^^ %products_dir% doesn't get expanded here
 robocopy publish\%x\  *.application *.deploy /s
 ===>                ^ or here
 copy Version.txt   
 ===>             ^^^^^^^ or here
)

C:\...>(
set products_dir=OutputMSI\ABC\products
 mkdir
 ===>  ^^^^^^^^^ %products_dir% still not expanded here
 robocopy publish\ABC\  *.application *.deploy /s
 ===>                ^ or here
 copy Version.txt   
 ===>             ^^^^^^^ or here
)
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

The variables get expanded on the `set` line, but then not after. What am I missing about `for` loops or `setlocal`?

I've tried without `EnableDelayedExpansion`, and I've tried doubling up the `%` around the variable names, but neither made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` - there is the word "enable" in it. It only *prepares* batch to use delayed expansion. To actually *use* a delayed variable, enclose it between `!` instead of `%`:

```
set var=XYZ
for %%x in (ABC DEF GHI) do (
    set var=%%x
    echo %%x, !var!, %var%
)
```